# Restrict bandwidth of certain website using Squid3

Tags: ubuntu, proxy, squid, cache

I have a Squid3 server and I'd like to restrict the bandwidth of certain websites.
For example:

How can I make www.example.org/* load at no more than 10KB/s?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your answer lies within **Delay Pools**

What you have to do is,

1. Make an access list that describes your traffic. In this case something like `acl LimitedDomains dstdomain example.com`
2. Define how many Delay Pools you need. Delay Pools are different *Bandwidth Rules*. i.e. `delay_pools 2`
3. Next define what class should each *Pool* be. i.e. `delay_class 1 1` which means that *Pool 1* will be *Class 1* (see bellow about classes
4. Match each pool with an *Access List*. i.e.

   delay_access 1 allow LimitedDomains

   delay_access 1 deny all
5. Then set the parameters of the *Pool*. The parameters depend on the Class you chose but essentially are the bandwidth limit in *Bytes* per IP/Network/User. i.e. `delay_parameters 10000/10000`

For more detailed information on Pools, Classes, etc look [here](http://www.visolve.com/squid/squid30/delaypools.php).

Comment: Thanks -- would you have a line-by-line working configuration example?  Thanks.

Comment: The examples I gave above are more or less what you want. You can use them as a guide and change accordingly. Cheers.